# What is different between elation and felicity

Tags: meaning

I checked both words on the dictionary.
Both meanings are 'happiness'.
When I looked at synonymous of elation,
'felicity' is not included.

Comment: Please add links to the definitions you looked up.

Answer (score 1):

As nouns the [difference](http://the-difference-between.com/elation/felicity) between *felicity* and *elation*  is that the former is *happiness* while the latter is *an exhilarating psychological state of pride and/or optimism*.

The antonym of [*elation*](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/elation) is depression, whereas that of [*felicity*](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/felicity)  is unhappiness.